# How to set the timing right for a delay loop in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to write a one-second delay loop in assembly language and I'm not sure what would be the count for the loop so that it'll delay for 1 second.

Here is what I have so far:

```
MOV   R1, #count

DELAY_LOOP:  
             SUBS   R1, R1, #1

             BNE  DELAY_LOOP
```

I'm using a Beaglebone Black. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there is a timer interrupt available, try to use that instead.

Comment: Check clock speed and how many clocks each instruction you use takes. Then divide. Or, if you are lazy and don't need a lot of precision, stick a big number in there and time the code with a watch, then scale that back.

Comment: Especially in modern CPUs; clock speed can be different for different CPUs, and/or can change while a CPU is running (due to power management - e.g. the "dynamic CPU frequency scaling" feature supported by the SoC that Beaglebone Black uses); and if neither of those things are possible there's still IRQs that "randomly" make a loop take longer than it should have. For these reasons, a delay loop is almost always a bug because it's impossible to determine the right count (and even when it's not a bug it's a portability and maintenance disaster). You should use an actual hardware timer instead.

Comment: This is actually part of part I of my project. Part II is where we use a timer to set the time. I think guess and check is the way to go for now. Thanks all!

Comment: In real life you never want to keep the CPU active using lots of power running a delay loop for a whole second.  The only good use-case for a delay loop is an interval too short to do accurately with a sleep/wake.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to get this right for ARM, particularly if you are running this on an operating system. Not possible to be accurate. Pure baremetal, no interrupts, you can hand tune it experimentally, but if you change the alignment the performance can change by quite a bit, not only due to caching as most folks will assume but also do to where the fetch lines lie and sweet spots for branch prediction if there is branch prediction and how it is implemented.  I use this exact loop to demonstrate this problem it is somewhat trivial.

The problem is not specific to ARM anything pipelined is often going to fetch more than one instruction per fetch transaction, the fetches are often on aligned boundaries for performance reasons, and there is a watermark in the prefetch buffer that receives this data that determines when to do the next fetch, the alignment of even these two instructions in a loop depending on where they lie can play havoc on execution performance, basically is it doing two fetch lines or one per loop, cache isnt relevant beyond the first pass, one or two fetch lines can still hit the cache.

But this all varies by architecture.  Mips fetching and buffering into the pipe, arm, x86, powerpc, etc all vary and probably vary by rev or generation of that architecture every couple three years the rules may change for the next version of that core

ARM and MIPS and other IP based cores (where the chip vendor implements the memory system) you can have the same exact version of the core but
the chip vendor or family to chip vendor or family differences can/will
affect performance, so even if you got kinda close on one chip, keep the
same alignment and other core settings performance can be different based
on the chip vendor/memory side.  Add dram to this equation, where the
performance of memory is not not-deterministic and you just make it that much worse.

If you go back to pre-pipelined days, where the execution was one instruction at a time, very predictable, a commonly used timed loop is done with the older PIC instruction set(s), extremely predictable and not uncommon to see timed loops used instead of a timer.  Has lead to a lot of folks trying to do this, after they learned/saw it on that architecture with other mcus and architectures (only to fail).

this is a very educational exercise and I recommend you try it.  use a timer as reference and sample it ideally with a single load instruction before and after the code under test.  If you are doing all of this on an operating system there might be enough noise that you dont actually see as much detail in the differences.  You will have created other cycle stealers that are added to the overall timing, in particular the calls to get the time before and after the code under test.